# finding/comparing dates when sometimes only NA's are present

Tags: r, date

I'm both new to coding in R (always used SPSS but have to use R for a project) and this website, so bear with me. Hopefully I'm both able to explain the problem and what I've tried.

My data looks somewhat like this:

```
    df <- data.frame (
        ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
        measurement = c (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
        date_event1 = c(NA, NA, "2021-02-15", NA, NA, NA, "2021-03-01", NA, NA),
        date_event2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2021-03-06", NA, NA, "2022-02-02", "2022-02-02")
      )

    df
ID measurement  date_event1 date_event2
1           1               <NA>        <NA>
1           2               <NA>        <NA>
1           3         2021-02-15        <NA>
2           1               <NA>        <NA>
2           2               <NA>  2021-03-06
2           3               <NA>        <NA>
2           4         2021-03-01        <NA>
3           1               <NA>  2022-02-02
3           2               <NA>  2022-02-02
```

I have patients (identified by ID) with a variable number of measurements (identified by measurement number and their date, so long-format data) and events (coded here as 'event1' and 'event2'). Events can be present for a particular patient and measurement (then coded with the date it occurred) or absent (then coded as NA).

Ultimately, my goal is to calculate intervals (in days) between two **first** events, if two are present. If no or only 1 event took place, the result should be NA. Desired output should look something like this:

```
ID measurement  date_event1 date_event2 interval
1           1               <NA>        <NA>       NA
1           2               <NA>        <NA>       NA
1           3         2021-02-15        <NA>       NA
2           1               <NA>        <NA>       **5**
2           2               <NA>  2021-03-06       **5**
2           3               <NA>        <NA>       **5**
2           4         2021-03-01        <NA>        5
3           1               <NA>  2022-02-02       **NA**
3           2               <NA>  2022-02-02       NA
```

Main issues here are:

- finding the first event using functions as 'min' will error if NA's are present.
- using the 'min(x, na.rm=TRUE)' as a solution doesn't work if IDs with only NA's are present

What I've tried:

```
   df <- df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
        arrange(ID, measurement) %>%
# creating 2 identifier variables if all rows for event1/event2 are NA
        mutate(allNA1 = ifelse(all(is.na(date_event1)), 1, 0)) %>%
        mutate(allNA2 = ifelse(all(is.na(date_event2)), 1, 0)) %>%
      ungroup()

# for simplicity, combining these two identifier variables into 1 
    df$test <- ifelse(df$allNA1 == 0 & df$allNA2 == 0, 1, NA)
 
# then using this combined identifier variable to only use mindate on IDs that have at least 1 event  
    df <- df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(mindate = if_else(test == 1, min(date_event1, na.rm=TRUE), NA_real_)) %>%
      ungroup ()
```

I haven't gotten to the comparing-dates step as finding the first date still produces the '*no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf*' warnings, even though I'm only mutating if test==1. What am I missing here? Are there easier solutions to my main problem? Thank you in advance!

Edit: forgot to add that the FIRST event should be used. Changes highlighted in bold.

Edit 2: made an error in the example, changed dates and intervals, also removed a column for simplicity.

Edit 3: Harre suggested to suppress warnings. Using the following did not work:

```
options(warn = -1)
df <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(interval = abs(min(date_event1, na.rm=TRUE) - min(date_event2, na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup()
options(warn = 1)
```

Edit 6/8/22:
Okay, so I managed to circumvent the problem:

```
df <- df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     # first recoding all missing values to an extremely late date
        mutate(date_event1 = if_else(is.na(date_event1), as.Date("2099-09-09"), date_event1)) %>%
        # then finding the earliest date (which are the non-2099-dates, if one was present)
        mutate(min_date_event1 = min(date_event1)) %>%
        # then recoding the 2099-dates back to NA
        mutate(min_date_event1= if_else(mindate == '2099-09-09', as.Date(NA_real_), mindate)) %>%
```

Which feels really inefficient for something I could do with 1 function in SPSS (AGGREGATE > FIRST). I'll checkmark my question but if anyone has an easier solution, feel free to add suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your *"goal is to calculate intervals (in days) between two events, if two are present. If no or only 1 event took place, the result should be NA"*, there is no need for anything else than converting to the `date`-type:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(interval = abs(as.Date(date_event2) - as.Date(date_event1)))
```

or

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date),
         interval = abs(date_event2 - date_event1))
```

Output:

```r
  ID measurement date_measurement date_event1 date_event2 interval
1  1           1       2020-01-01        <NA>        <NA>  NA days
2  1           2       2020-01-05        <NA>        <NA>  NA days
3  1           3       2020-01-10  2021-02-15        <NA>  NA days
4  2           1       2021-02-01        <NA>  2021-03-01  NA days
5  2           2       2021-02-15        <NA>  2021-03-05  NA days
6  2           3       2021-03-01        <NA>        <NA>  NA days
7  2           4       2021-04-01  2021-03-01  2021-03-06   5 days
8  3           1       2022-01-01        <NA>  2022-02-02  NA days
9  3           2       2022-03-01        <NA>        <NA>  NA days
```

**Update:**

I this case you'll just want to suppress the warning as it doesn't influence the result (shown below). Alternatively you could arrange by the date and pick the first using `first()` no matter if it's NA or not.

```r
df |>
    group_by(ID) |>
    mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date),
           across(starts_with("date_event"), ~ suppressWarnings(min(., na.rm = TRUE)), .names = "{.col}_min"),
           interval = na_if(abs(date_event2_min - date_event1_min), Inf)) |>
    ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 9 × 7
     ID measurement date_event1 date_event2 date_event1_min date_event2_min interval
  <dbl>       <dbl> <date>      <date>      <date>          <date>          <drtn>  
1     1           1 NA          NA          2021-02-15      NA              NA days 
2     1           2 NA          NA          2021-02-15      NA              NA days 
3     1           3 2021-02-15  NA          2021-02-15      NA              NA days 
4     2           1 NA          NA          2021-03-01      2021-03-06       5 days 
5     2           2 NA          2021-03-06  2021-03-01      2021-03-06       5 days 
6     2           3 NA          NA          2021-03-01      2021-03-06       5 days 
7     2           4 2021-03-01  NA          2021-03-01      2021-03-06       5 days 
8     3           1 NA          2022-02-02  NA              2022-02-02      NA days 
9     3           2 NA          2022-02-02  NA              2022-02-02      NA days
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Harre. I forgot to mention that the FIRST event should be used within a patient ID, so calculations within a row (such as yours) do not work - I modified my initial post slightly. Problem is the 'min()' function doesn't work with NAs

Comment: I am sorry, it's not clear for me: The updated row belongs to ID 3 not 2. There is more than 5 days between 2021-03-01 and 2022-02-02. In my end the `min` function works fine on dates, but you'll need to be very specific of the behavior you need.

Comment: Sorry about that, re-edited the data again. To summarise:
- first ID has only NAs in event1
- second ID has both a valid event1 and event2
- third ID has only NAs in event2
I need the first (earliest) event within an ID for both events, and then to calculate the interval between those two dates. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd expect you'd just want to suppress the warning as it has no influence on the result.

Comment: I tried the following (will add code to the original post), but that causes an endless processing state, comparable to when warnings were on but just without displaying the warnings?

Comment: See my post update too. Doesn’t that work either?

Comment: Results in a similar processing-state. Perhaps it works in smaller datasets but is too CPU-heavy as I have roughly 11 billion rows?

Comment: Does endless mean endless or just that it's still working on it? A grouping, arranging etc. is something on 11 billion rows, so you might just need to wait. Maybe try on a subset first. We could also think of other approaches. While I am not strong in `data.table` solutions, these are often the fastest here when benchmarking.

Comment: It's still working on it: if I don't suppress the warnings, I can see the group numbers increasing, but it would take way too much time to let it finish. With other functions such as mutate() I don't really notice the large size of the dataset

Comment: I managed to circumvent my problem, @Harre. I've edited my first post.

Comment: Nice work-around. Don’t feel that you have to accept my answer. You can also post one yourself. I am sure there is other ways, but it’s difficult with problems that doesn’t exist in the smaller samples suitable for this site. Thanks for the update